# You can have your API and eat (consume) it in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I have made an API that returns json in Laravel. (**routes/api.php**)

Now I want to consume said API inside my `web`-side of the project (**routes/web.php** (including middleware), **blade views** etc.).

The current solution that I have is something like this:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    // password1 == password2 etc (form logic / validation)
    $internal_request = Request::create($this->base_api_url . 'register', 'POST');
    $internal_request->replace($request->input());
    $response = Route::dispatch($internal_request);
}
```

Which "forwards" the request to the api counterpart to my api if the form is valid. But I have the feeling this is not really best practice or smart. Other routes except `login` and `register` use the api token stored in session to make the calls. they append the token "x-token" as a header to `$internal_request`. Is it better to do this in middleware? Is there some example of a best implementation somewhere?

My API has a method like this:

`POST api/register`
Which check if the the required fields exist and have the rigt format (validation)

and my web route has `/register`

This will first check if the passwords match from the password validation inputs (pass1 == pass2) and will then pass it to the api equivalent.

So `web` should be a superset (validation wise) of `api`.

Comment: Focus on single responsibility, then factor out the common work. Web, CLI, and API are responsible for unmarshalling and validating input. Once satisfied with the input, they then hand the validated input to a common service that carries out the desired task. Finally, they take that common service's result and marshal it back to the user. Loopback calls like this work, but they are redundant because marshalling / unmarshalling happens twice. It also makes testing more difficult than necessary, as you end up relying on integration testing and often testing the same paths over and over again.

Comment: @bishop Yes, I was thinking about doing more inside the model and less in the controllers. That way model = single responsibility. But is there some hard defined way?

Comment: No, there is no hard defined way because of TIMTOWTDI. I agree that pushing most work into the model service layer is the way to go. But, I stress the *service* portion: lots of model-type classes working on different parts of the overall problem of data transformation, rather than a few gigantic models that do way too much.

Comment: One of the reasons I did not do this, is the way laravel's validation uses a `request` object by default, which intuitively feels like: "so do it in the controller". My project is relativly small with <10 models, so I don't think your concerns apply this exact situation, however I will keep it in mind!

Comment: Your project is 10 models *now*. Beware success.

Comment: @bishop I like that last one, thanks. I just hoped there was a way that everybody agreed upon, because I love the laravel framework and would like to use it the best way possible for later (like everyone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to apply the same logic to both api and web requests and you may just want to (a) validate the form for a web request and/or (b) wrap the response in json for an API request.

I think the best way to do this would be to **refer to the same controller and method for both web and api requests**, so for example:

In your routes/web.php, add `Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@register`);`

And in your routes/api.php, add `Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@register`)`

So eventually both requests (api/register and /register) hit the same controller 
and method.

Now, in your controller, you can perform the extra actions depending on request like so:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    if(!$request->expectsJson()) { // you may want to swap this with $request->isJson() depending on the HTTP headers for your app
        $this->validateWebRegistration($request); // your validation logic specific to web requests here
    }

    // common logic here (including validation); store result as $result

    if($request->expectsJson()) { // based on HTTP headers as above
        return response()->json($result);
    } else {
        return view('register', $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will edit my question, so you understand the difference between them better :)

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your updated question. I didn't understand the first part of your question though. What is the `x-token`? Are you referring to a CSRF token?

Comment: X-token is my api token that I generate on api/login and should be send as a header with every request.

Comment: If it's supposed to be sent as a request header, shouldn't it be the client's responsibility to do so rather than the server? If you need to set a response header on successful login, you can add that logic to your logincontroller

Comment: Well I thought about that, but Web has more (a superset) of validation and works with a session. The api is stateless.

Comment: Instead of modifying the request to include a header and then validating the same header, it's always better to just not validate for the api (like suggested in my answer above)

Comment: I will think about it some longer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I will do it this way:

- detect in the controller if we deal with an API request or a Web request
- detect the corrosponding credentials (token or session)
- do form logic if web
- do api logic in both situations
- create a view or json response accordingly
- all in the same controller