# Security Issue in Token in front end and API

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel as API and AngularJs for Frontend.

From API, data is coming like this.

```
$data = [
    'Token'     =>  \Auth::guard("api")->user()->api_token,
];

return  \Response::json([
    'Status'    =>  true,
    'Message'   =>  'ok',
    'Data'      =>  $data,
], $Code);
```

and in the AndularJs Controller, it is being saved like below in cookies.

```
$cookies.put("Token", response.data.Data.Token);
```

and then from the cookies, it is being retrieved like this

```
$cookies.get("Token");
```

I think, this are security problems like if anyone gets to know the token, they would submit any request.

Could u suggest any better way?

Can we do something like...get the current device info(android or desktop or etc..) and then save the final encrypted value(token + device info) into cookie or some other media? Then at the time of sending request to api....we could decrypt to make sure if that is stolen token or not...? Is there anything I could use which is unique in all devices?

Comment: The current way I use is letting a session in PHP store the token. Of course you want to use angular, but maybe you can write some middleware that appends the token to your request based on your session and if the request is ajax/xhr. I find this a interesting subject as well, hence my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250310/you-can-have-your-api-and-eat-consume-it-in-laravel

Comment: Actually my concern is...whatever you send from api to frontend...will get saved in cookies or some other means.. here concern is how secure the token is at frontend?

Comment: The token does not ever have to reach the browser, only the session  (**not** API) token has to be stored somewhere in the frontend indeed (so a cookie). But in laravel this cookie is only a session identifier (of your session driver is **not** cookie, but it will still be encrypted if it is) and next to that will not be able to be read outside of your domain.

Comment: Can we do something like...get the current device info(android or desktop or etc..) and then save the final encrypted value(token + device info) into cookie or some other media? Then at the time of sending request to api....we could decrypt to make sure if that is stolen token or not...? Is there anything I could use which is unique in all devices?

Comment: That would be a really custom implementation, while there are better ways already layed out for you. Let's repeat: I think it's best to let angular (the browser at all for that matter) know the api token, just keep it serversided and let the session handle the authentication for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Its mandatory to use TLS/SSL (HTTP over TLS or HTTPS) in conjunction with web tokens to insure secure communications between your API and the angular client,in most cases that will be enough, you might add extra layer by encrypting the token payload itself using the JSON Web Encryption (JWE) specification before storing it in your cookies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution is [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport). This way at Frontend you store `client_id` and `client_secret`, and then use use them to exchange for authorization token.

Comment: What if someone steals the id and secret?